# Find a value in one table, copying data in a different column from same row and then paste into another table

Tags: excel, vba

So I have two tables. One table contains a big list of jobs/names etc. and the other table is essentially a 'job tracker' listing all the jobs and when they're due.

I have certain jobs that I must do every month, or quarter. At the start of every month I have to go through my stored list, copy all the jobs marked as month/quarter and then paste them into my job tracker. We're about 110 a month minimum so I'm trying to automate it as nothing ever changes on the job information - just the date due.

What I want to do is check in my table for any job marked as 'Monthly', copy the Job Name of that row and paste it into my job tracker.

I'm intentionally doing it all separately using If Statements as I'll create a UserForm that allows me (and other users) to check a box to decide if they want to book in certain jobs, i.e. Monthly, Quarterly, Biannually etc.

For example, I want the code to the do the following:

```
If Frequency In Job Table = "Monthly" Then

Copy the Job Name 

Paste the Job Name into Job Tracking table

End If
```

Which essentially would create this output:
[Ideal result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILotz.png)
This is the code I've got so far. My problem is that it only works for one result and isn't pulling each and every result through.

```
Sub Test_IF_MATCH()

Dim ProdWS As Worksheet
Dim ProdTBL As ListObject
Dim ProdVAL As ListColumn
Dim newRow As ListRow
Dim newCol As ListColumn
Dim ColNum As Long
Dim TargetTBL As ListObject
Dim TargetVAL As ListColumn
Dim TargetVAL_F As ListColumn

Dim TargetRange As Range
Dim curr As Range

Set ProdWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTWS")       '#####Edit here for deployment
Set ProdTBL = ProdWS.ListObjects("TESTTBL")            '#####Edit here for deployment
Set ProdVAL = ProdTBL.ListColumns("ValToMove")         '#####Edit here for deployment
Set ProdVAL_CPY = ProdTBL.ListColumns("Frequency")     '#####Edit here for deployment

Set TargetTBL = ProdWS.ListObjects("TESTTBL2")         '#####Edit here for deployment
Set newRow = TargetTBL.ListRows.Add
Set newCol = TargetTBL.ListColumns("Frequency output") '#####Edit here for deployment
ColNum = newCol.Index


'########################## Variables ##########################'
Set TargetRange = ProdTBL.ListColumns("Frequency").DataBodyRange
FindByFrequency = "Monthly"
'###############################################################'

'############## Index match values ##############'

Dim LookUpWS As Worksheet
Dim LookupRNG As Range

Set LookUpWS = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTWS")
Set LookupRNG = LookUpWS.ListObjects("TESTTBL").DataBodyRange

'## Match one

Dim M1_Search As Range
Dim Test_TBL As ListObject

Set Test_TBL = LookUpWS.ListObjects("TESTTBL")
Set M1_Search = Test_TBL.ListColumns("Frequency").DataBodyRange

MatchOne = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(FindByFrequency, M1_Search, 0)

'## Match two

Dim M2_Search As Range
Set M2_Search = LookUpWS.Range("A1:C1")

MatchTwo = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Job name", M2_Search, 0)

'################################################'

For Each curr In TargetRange

    If curr.Value = FindByFrequency Then
        Result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(LookupRNG, MatchOne, MatchTwo)
            With newRow
                .Range(, ColNum) = Result
            End With
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

Is anyone able to help please? At my wits end on this now and have reached the end of my abilities to Google and trial/error the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of using a filter to grab all instances from your table where the Frequency column = Monthly:

```
Sub tgr()

    Dim wsData As Worksheet
    Dim oData As ListObject
    Dim rMatch As Range
    Dim FindByFrequency As String
    Dim FilterCol As String

    Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TESTWS")
    Set oData = wsData.ListObjects("TESTTBL")
    FindByFrequency = "Monthly"
    FilterCol = "Frequency"

    With oData.Range
        .AutoFilter oData.ListColumns(FilterCol).Index, FindByFrequency, xlFilterValues
        On Error Resume Next    'Prevent error if no cells are found
        Set rMatch = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0         'Remove On Error Resume Next condition
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    If Not rMatch Is Nothing Then
        rMatch.Copy
        wsData.Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks very much for helping, really appreciate your way of approaching the problem - I hadn't thought of that! Regrettably, I don't know if I explained myself well enough in my introduction so I apologise for any of your time wasted. The macro needs to only copy the corresponding cell (which I fixed easily just by adding the column number to the Set rMatch.. line. My problem is however pasting these values into a new table. I can't seem to get it to add the right amount of rows and then paste the data. I can get it to make one row but not the required amount

Answer (score 0):

So based off Tigeravatar's answer I managed to adapt the code to fit what I need.

It was almost there so a huge, huge thank you to Tigeravatar for taking the time - it's sincerely appreciated. Sometimes we just need to see a problem with fresh eyes to overcome it eh

Below is the code I used. It now copies just the target Job Name (instead of the whole table) and pastes it into the new table by adding a new row.

I've added a few comments to explain what I've done incase this helps anyone else.

```
Sub tgr()

Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim oData As ListObject
Dim oTarget As ListObject
Dim rMatch As Range
Dim FindByFrequency As String
Dim FilterCol As String
Dim newRow As ListRow
Dim colIndex As Integer
Dim colName As ListColumn

Set wsData = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test")

'The source of all the main data to pull from.
Set oData = wsData.ListObjects("PRODUCT")

'Gets the column index number of the column name that we want a result from
Set colName = oData.ListColumns("Job name")
colIndex = colName.Index

'Sets the destination for the data
Set oTarget = wsData.ListObjects("TRACKER")

'Adds a new row to the destination table
Set newRow = oTarget.ListRows.Add(AlwaysInsert:=True)

'############### Variable here ###############'
FindByFrequency = "Monthly"
'#############################################'

FilterCol = "Frequency"

'Copies the data that matches the criteria
With oData.Range
    .AutoFilter oData.ListColumns(FilterCol).Index, FindByFrequency, xlFilterValues
    On Error Resume Next    'Prevent error if no cells are found
    Set rMatch = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, colIndex).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0         'Remove On Error Resume Next condition
    .AutoFilter
End With

'Debug - not essential
Debug.Print "Add " & rMatch.Count & " rows"

'Starts to paste the values to destination
If Not rMatch Is Nothing Then
    rMatch.Copy
    'Creates a new row for each values copied and pastes as values to destination
    newRow.Range.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
End If


End Sub
```